# Adding arbitrary/custom tags to (ex)ctags file

Tags: c, exuberant-ctags

I have C code which contains references to requirement numbers of a very simple pattern:

```
/**
 * Lorem ipsum, you know the routine.
 * See also: Requirement R12345.
 */
```

In other words, the requirement is an `R` followed by exactly 5 decimal digits. I would like to add those to my ctags file so I can jump to tags with `:ta R12345`. I've read the exctags docs up and down, but could not find any option that would allow this.

I thought of grepping for the requirements and patching up the tags file with appropriate lines (using search for line numbers probably makes this easy) but I am not sure if the extra lines would need to be merged or just appended, and what the exact format is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must be blind not recognizing the `--regex-<LANG>` option. This does exactly what I want:

```
ctags ... --regex-c='/\<(R[[:digit:]]{5})\>/\1/' *.[ch]
```

This creates the tags file with additional tags for all R12345 requirements.